# Print birthday in Java using objects and multiple classes

Tags: java, object

I am just learning about objects and class definitions.  This assignment is meant to create an object named birthday and print it in a reader friendly format.  When I run it, it prints "moredates.Date@15db9742" when it should be printing "4/21/1999".

Below is my Date class.

```
package moredates;


public class Date {
    int year, month, day;

public Date(){
this.year=0;
this.month=0;
this.day=0;
}
public Date(int year, int month, int day){
this.year=year;
this.month=month;
this.day=day;

}
 public static void printDate (Date d){
    System.out.println(d.month + "/" + d.day + "/" + d.year);
}
}
```

And here is my main class which is in a different file, but in the same package.

```
package moredates;

public class MoreDates {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Date birthday= new Date();
birthday.month=4;
birthday.day=21;
birthday.year=1999;
Date d=birthday;
System.out.print(d);

    }

}
```

Comment: Give your Date class a decent valid `public String toString()` method override. For the details of this, please check out the answers to the [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4) used to close your question.

Comment: Side suggestion 2: rename that Date class. You will want to avoid giving your class a name that clashes with important core Java classes.

Comment: change last line to Date.printDate(d).

Comment: @Shiping thank you, that did the trick!